# Getting error message as "Network issue" while making API call to a remote API server

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, axios, android-virtual-device

I am new to React Native development. I have some experience with React JS. I am developing simple login page which sends "username"and "password" to my remote API while clicking the "Loign" button. I am trying to integrating remote API with my React Native application using Axios. While making an API call I am getting the error message as "Network Error".

Below is the code snippet:

[Code snippet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x71Gj.png)

**Note**:
I am using React Navtive version 0.69.0.
I am behind corporate network and it has some firewall.
**My remote server uses HTTPS protocol.**
For testing purpose I am using Android Virtual Device(AVD) which runs with Android version 12.
The API don't want the bearer token for authorization.

I tried all possible ways that are mentioned in some stack overflow posts like adding "android:usesCleartextTraffic=true" in "AndroidManifest.xml", etc, and nothing resolves my issue. I asks ChatGPT for this and it mentions some suggestions, I tried everything but still not resolved. I even tried installing the application in my mobile and tested, again getting the same error. I just want to know why this issue occurs even after all possible ways and how to resolve it. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It will help us a lot if you can create a small project that recreates the error. Then post the code for that project directly in your question, not a screenshot. Also include the entire error message. We can try to help you from there.